# How can I implement Tracing in Spring Boot without using Sleuth?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, trace

I'm trying to implement Tracing during logging in my Spring Boot application, Sleuth is one option for me implement without doing any coding sort or thing.
But my problem is with customization. I went through the source code of sleuth and found out that they're modifying the logging level pattern to implement tracing, how can I modify the logging pattern without adding the sleuth dependency?

Comment: They only modify the pattern so the ids can be added... That has nothing to do with all the other stuff needed to implement tracing. If it was only as easy as modifying the log pattern.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add dependency to project ,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
             <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

2.I had an existing `logback-spring.xml` & there I had to change logging pattern. Without changing log pattern, ids were not showing in logs ,

**Existing Pattern** - `%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n`

**New  Pattern**- `%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] [%X{X-B3-TraceId},%X{X-B3-SpanId},%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId},%X{X-Span-Export}] %msg%n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use somethin like this:

```
package com.team.monitoring;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import com.codahale.metrics.Slf4jReporter;

public final class MetricRegistrySingleton {

    public static final MetricRegistry metrics = new MetricRegistry();

    static {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.team.monitoring");
        final Slf4jReporter reporter = Slf4jReporter.forRegistry(metrics).outputTo(logger).convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS).convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
        reporter.start(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    private MetricRegistrySingleton() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

}
```

In this way by slf4j you can configure the logger programatically, you dont need configuration files.

Your pom.xml must look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.javacodegeeks</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4-spring-boot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>slf4-spring-boot</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```